# Пароль с солью (salt+password)

Tags: безопасность, хеширование

Есть ли смысл "солить" пароль несколько раз?

```
$db_password = $salt.hash_func($salt.hash_func($salt.hash_func($salt.$my_password)))
```

Или это не повысит эффективность?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Knes](/users/2825/knes) есть прямой смысл солить несколько раз и использовать несколько разных хэш алгоритмов. Смысл здесь такой, что радужные таблицы составляются для конкретного хэш алгоритма, а поскольку соль хранится в открытом доступе то подобрать алгоритм соления пароля при однократном солении все же можно, а если соление примерно такое:

```
db_password=hash1(salt1/2+hash2(password+salt2)+salt1/2)
```

то, чтобы расколотить такую комбинацию нужно сначала провести реверс-инжиниринг кода (чтобы раскрыть алгоритм соления) и только потом применить радужные таблицы совместно с брут-форсом.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю что здесь большую роль играет длина и сложность самой соли а не количество раз ее использования.

Comment: к сожалению, кроме радужных таблиц я не знаю более-менее надежного способа взломать хэш. От этого способа соль защищает неплохо уже после первого примененя. Другое дело, конечно, суммарная длина должна превышать длину хэша.

Что касается сложности... зачем? Она же в открытом виде хранится и нужна только для удлиннения пароля. Вот разную ее для разных паролей делать стоит, чтобы нельзя было создать единый набор, но с этой задачей справится врапнутый логин. Я то-то упустил?